# Excel Split out Array for Different Colours

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I had help with this code below, that works like a dream, it finds words from all 5 search textboxes and highlights them in red and adds a count to one of the columns.  However i want to do the same but for box 1 word is in red and box 2 the word it finds it highlights in green and box 3 in orange etc etc.  Is it possible to split out from the array which text box goes to which section of code, then could I change the second full set of loops to look for the word n the second textbox and make the word green?

I hope that makes sense?

```
Worksheets("Questions").Activate
Dim sPos As Long, sLen As Long
Dim SRrng As Range, cell2 As Range
Dim mywords As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Set SRrng = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:E4000")

mywords = Array(UsrFormSearch.TxtSearch1.Value, UsrFormSearch.TxtSearch2.Value, 
UsrFormSearch.TxtSearch3.Value, UsrFormSearch.TxtSearch4.Value, UsrFormSearch.TxtSearch5.Value)

Dim m As Byte
Dim c As Range
Dim firstAddress As String

Dim CountArray() As Variant
ReDim CountArray(1 To SRrng.Rows.Count, 1 To 1)

For m = 0 To UBound(mywords)
With ActiveSheet.Range("B2:E4000")
    Set c = .Find(mywords(m), LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        
        Do
            For i = 1 To Len(c.Value)
                sPos = InStr(i, c.Value, mywords(m))
                sLen = Len(mywords(m))
                If (sPos <> 0) Then
               
                 c.Characters(Start:=sPos, Length:=sLen).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                 c.Characters(Start:=sPos, Length:=sLen).Font.Bold = True
                 i = sPos + Len(mywords(m)) - 1
                 CountArray(c.Row - SRrng.Cells(1, 1).Row + 1, 1) = CountArray(c.Row - SRrng.Cells(1, 
1).Row + 1, 1) + 1
                 
                End If
                
            Next i
                
                
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
            If firstAddress = c.Address Then Exit Do
            
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing
        
    End If
End With
Next m
SRrng.Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, SRrng.Columns.Count).Resize(UBound(CountArray, 1), 1).Value2 = CountArray
```

Comment: Il need to verify that after lunch so i wont put it as an answer yet but you could probably set your RGB parameters as variables ex :`R as long`, `G as Long` etc, and change R,G and B each loop (add a certain amount or fix it in fucntion of the `m` loop value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would work. Just add in a second array of your RGB values which you can reference during each loop cycle.

```
Sub TestColor()
    Worksheets("Questions").Activate
    Dim sPos As Long, sLen As Long
    Dim SRrng As Range, cell2 As Range
    Dim mywords As Variant, myColors As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Set SRrng = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:E4000")
    
    With UsrFormSearch ' Think the .Value is superfluous - add back in if issues arise
        mywords = Array(.TxtSearch1, .TxtSearch2, .TxtSearch3, .TxtSearch4, .TxtSearch5)
    End With
    myColors = Array(RGB(255, 0, 0), RGB(0, 255, 0), RGB(255, 255, 0), RGB(255, 0, 255), RGB(0, 0, 255))
    
    Dim m As Byte
    Dim c As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String
    
    Dim CountArray() As Variant
    ReDim CountArray(1 To SRrng.Rows.Count, 1 To 1)
    
    For m = 0 To UBound(mywords)
    With ActiveSheet.Range("B2:E4000")
        Set c = .Find(mywords(m), LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                For i = 1 To Len(c.Value)
                    sPos = InStr(i, c.Value, mywords(m))
                    sLen = Len(mywords(m))
                    If (sPos <> 0) Then
                     c.Characters(Start:=sPos, Length:=sLen).Font.Color = myColors(m)
                     c.Characters(Start:=sPos, Length:=sLen).Font.Bold = True
                     i = sPos + Len(mywords(m)) - 1
                     CountArray(c.Row - SRrng.Cells(1, 1).Row + 1, 1) = CountArray(c.Row - SRrng.Cells(1, 1).Row + 1, 1) + 1
                    End If
                Next i
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
                If firstAddress = c.Address Then Exit Do
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing
        End If
    End With
    Next m
    SRrng.Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, SRrng.Columns.Count).Resize(UBound(CountArray, 1), 1).Value2 = CountArray
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Sorry i have been locked down due to covid, this is absolutely perfect, the one i wrote was looping through each time for each word in the search and was taking forever tor run.  Am i supposed to open another ticket for another question?  The questions is, i have it set to add 1 value in the final column for every word it finds, but if you wanted to add value 1 for textbox1search and 2 for textbox2search, and so on.  Would i be better doing looping through each time or can this also be done by adding an array with the value and linking it to the existing routine.  Many thanks. VBVirg